# Should I use a for statement here or not?

Tags: python

I have this question and I want your expert answers about it, because I want to get better in programming.

```
"""
The parameter s_str is a string. The parameter n is an int > 0.
The function x() should return the last n characters of s_str if
s_str has a length >= n, or the empty string if s_str has a length < n

Example:
    x('abcdef', 3)  == 'def'
"""
```

So, I could build the exact code with or without the for statement and it would give me (print) the same values, but I don't know what is the more common way to do it. If I'd go for a for statement, I'd do this:

```
for i in s_str:
    if len(s_str) >= n:
        return a_str[-n:]
    elif len(s_str) < n:
        return ''
```

Is the idea of using a for statement wrong if you know in advance that you are not going to use `i`, in this case? I could easily remove the `for statement` and still get the right answer, so is that enough reason not to use it?

Comment: No, it's not about while or for: is it a bad practice not to use them? Or bad practice to use solely an if?

Comment: There's no reason to use a `for` loop here.  `for` loops are for iterating over something, when you want to look at all the items in a `list` or something.  It's "bad practice" to write code that doesn't serve a purpose

Comment: Oh I didn't see the code exactly , even no need for loop here.

Comment: Thank you @PatrickHaugh! Appreciate the help a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"so is that enough reason not to use it?"

Yes. Simple is better than complex.

Comment: So, what you are saying is that I don't need to use it, because less is more. So it's not a bad practice to use just an if statement, without a while or for?

Comment: Correct. You should actively try to make your code as simple and easy to read/follow as possible. Having "extra" code is generally frowned upon.

Comment: Thanks, appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

There are cases in which a for loop is justified even if you do not intend to use the loop index (e.g when you want to preform a certain task n times). Having said that, this problem can be solved in a more elegant way, as you have shown.

Also please note that your code iterates over the string `len(str)` times, except it returns in the first iteration, so the for loop in this case is redundant.

Comment: Yes, I get the idea now. Not write code that you don't need to use, even though it seems "weird" just to have an if statement there. Thanks, Aviv.

Answer (score 1):

You dont actually need a for loop

```
if len(a_str) >= n:
        return a_str[-n:]
```

it is better and simple too.